# Jquery PLugin NiceScroll and Zindex don´t change

Tags: jquery, z-index, nicescroll

I have div in position fixed and overflow auto , the case it´s i use nicescroll for change as see the people scrollbar and customize it

The case it´s all it´s perfect but the problem it´s with z-index of scrollbar , and i can see scrollbarr under the div , this it´s a big problem because it´s impossible use this scrollbar

This scrollbar works in google chrome but show under div for scroll in firefox

**My code it´s :**

> ```
> <script>
> jQuery(document).ready(
> function() 
> {
> jQuery("#front_lateral").niceScroll({
> railalign: 'right',
> zindex:99999999,
> enablekeyboard:'true',
> cursorcolor:"#ff0000",
> background:"#ff0000",
> cursorborder:"-10px solid #ff0000",
> cursorborderradius:"1px",
> autohidemode: 'false',
> cursorwidth: '1px', 
> cursorcolor: '#dddddd', 
> smoothscroll:'true',
> railpadding:{top:0,right:0,left:0,bottom:0}
> }).resize();
> }
> );
> </script>
> ```

Big problem it´s don´t respect the z-index value i put inside , and continue to see under div in dixed position

Thank´ss regards

Answer (score 0):

I guess you solved it in 10 months, but i will give answer for other readers:

Try `zindex:'99999999'` to work it.